# TikZ - writing text above and below bent line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add some text/numbers above and below the middle of a line. Somehow, I have troubles finding out how this is possible.

This [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96846/how-to-place-label-in-middle-of-line-above-and-below-with-tikz) did not help, because I cannot transfer the solutions from there to my case.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex,align=center,
latent/.style={circle,draw, thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10mm},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
mean/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
    size=10mm},
paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
variance/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth', bend left=270, looseness=2},
arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=1ex, shorten <=1ex, bend angle=45}
]

\node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {LV1};
\node [latent] (LV2) [right =10 cm of LV1]  {LV1};
\draw [<->, bend angle=45, bend left]  (LV1) to (LV2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want `\draw [<->, bend angle=45, bend left]  (LV1) to node[below] {a} node[above] {b} (LV2);`?

Comment: Completely unrelated note: `\title`, `\author` and `\maketitle` are not mandatory (or rather, the first two are only mandatory if the third is used), so for examples such as these you may as well remove them altogether. Same for the empty `\section`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Want to write up an answer? You could mention `pos` and `sloped` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the very same approach of your linked post here as well. The only difference is the use of the `to` syntax instead of the `--` form. In your example, this would look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    ,>=latex
    ,latent/.style={%
        ,circle
        ,draw
        ,thick
        ,minimum size=10mm
        }
    ]   
    \node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {LV1};
    \node [latent] (LV2) [right =10 cm of LV1]  {LV1};
    \draw [<->, bend angle=45, bend left]  (LV1) to node[below] {a} node[above] {b} (LV2);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place the label somewhere else along that path, you can add the option `pos=.9` or `near end` (or other values) to your `node[...]`. If you want the label to follow the curvature of your arc, you may want to set the option `sloped` as well.