# Math equation in Tikzpicture node

Tags: tikz-pgf

This codes compiles a Hasse diagram of a diamond lattice. Now, I want to replace the 0-node by a \wedge b. However, when I replace all instances of 0 by a \wedge b, I get an error. Any help on how to resolve this issue?

\begin{tikzpicture}

```
  \node [mynode,label=above:1] (1) at (0,0) {};
  \node [mynode,below left  = of 1,label=left:a] (a)  {};
  \node [mynode,below right = of 1,label=right:b] (b) {};
  \node [mynode,below right = of a,label=below:0] (0) {};
  \node [mynode,below       = of 1,label=right:c] (c) {};

  \draw (1) -- (a) 
        (1) -- (c) 
        (1) -- (b)
        (c) -- (0)
        (a) -- (0) 
        (b) -- (0);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You are naming a node 0, and  node names are converted to macro names.  Since it is just a name, use `wedge b` (no backslash).

Comment: Then my node becomes 'a wedge b'. However, I want the mathematical symbol for \wedge.

Comment: I deleted the the mynodes, but I still get an error.

Comment: @J.Bosser Please add a fully compilable example so we can provide help.

Comment: Doesn't `label=below:$\wedge$` work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., yes this works!

Comment: Another question: how does one places label next to the lines?

Comment: Right, just as in normal text, there are things that only works in math mode, and then you need to switch to math mode. A TikZ  label/node is no different from normal text in that respect.  Node next to line: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96846/how-to-place-label-in-middle-of-line-above-and-below-with-tikz

Comment: To place a label (all labels are really nodes) next to a line, you can use `\draw (A) -- (B) node[midway, sloped, above]{text};`